# Proper approach to showing subviews using Vue

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and trying to observe the paradigm of it, I checked the page, did the examples and compared to Angular, MVC etc. that I'm substantially convenient with.

My scenario is as follows. There's a navbar on the static landing *index.html* page. Below it, there a div tagged for my view application called *#vapp*. As the user clicks on the different menus, I want the div *vapp* to be repopulated with:

1. the HTML code for that certain view,
2. data that's going be used in the table(s) and lists in it.

My approach would be to change the value of *vapp.data* to correspond to the one needed in the view (making that field my viewmodel, kind of). However, I'm a bit stuck on the routing part. Should I render the HTML to be Vue'd in the click event?

Perhaps I'm influenced by Angular but spontaneously I'd like to see a template in a separate HTML file that is piped (pushed, rendered - whatever the right naming is) into a part of my *vapp* div **while** at the same time letting it be able to access (and preferably be bound to) the data provided in the *data* field of the Vue object.

Is that the appropriate approach? Or is the paradigm behind Vue to create and maintain a new Vue object for each "page" being rendered?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709370/two-way-binding-between-controller-in-routerview-and-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used angular but in Vue you can implement an SPA by using [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/).

The approach is to have one page that serves all your components, and each component itself can be made up of multiple components. So firstly you set up a router like so:

```
// import top level components
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

// Define routes, each route serves up a component
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

// Create a router
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

// Mount it to your div
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

In your `HTML` you then do:

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- links you registered earlier -->
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
   <!-- All content will be served up here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Now vue will serve up `Foo` and `Bar` when those links are clicked.

As for serving up data, each component in a single file component is self contained, so you put the template, style and view model (data) relating to that component in one file:

```
<template>
  <div>
  {{message}}
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

</template>

<script>
  // import components to be used in this component
  import myComponent from './myComponent'

  export default{
     // register imported components
     components: {
       myComponent
     },
     data(){
       return {
         message: 'Foo'
       }
     }
  }
</script>
```

These need to be compiled with something like `webpack` or `browserify`.

Essentially in the end you have a bunch of self contained components being served up by the router as the user navigates, and each component contains all the components it needs to function.

Comment: The export and import in the component is confusing to me. How would it be solved in old JavaScript? Import is require(), right? And export?

Comment: Yes, `import` is `require`  and `export default` is similar to `module.exports`.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to work (regardless of *import* or *require()*). Where does the router configuration in your example go? I have it in my *index.js* but it's not working (*unexpected token import*). Perhaps I'm supposed to put it somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) installed? You will need this as a transform if you are using ES2015 syntax. You may want to take a look at [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) which provides scaffolding for the most common `Vue` setups so you don't have to do all the boilerplate stuff yourself.

Comment: I have *vue-cli* installed but I'm unsure if using it right. Perhaps I'm not understanding what the scaffolding means? Is it enough to have it installed and saved in the configuration JSON file? The part that I'm not getting is that I apparently do have ES6 support because I can do staff in that syntax and I can instantiate Vue. It's the [router that bugs me like I asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827986/unable-to-create-vue-router-instance-in-javascript). I think I'm close but missing the last part due to noobiness in the area (10+ year of C# will do that to you).

Comment: So, to summarize, I removed the imports from your code to avoid that issue and go with plain strings as components. All seems to work except for the stupid router that won't instantiate. Any hints on what I might be missing? (The router isn't stupid, of course - rather me...)

Comment: Have you included `Vue.use(VueRouter)` at the top of your router file? you will need to if you are using a module system.

Comment: Ahem... My router file? What file are we talking about here, exactly? Are you referring to the *index.js* that is linked to from the landing page *index.html*?

Comment: I have the *Vue.use(VueRouter);* right before the *const router = new VueRouter({ routes });* part, if that's what you mean. If not, then I'm sorrely lost again, hehe.

Comment: No, that's correct. Have you imported vue router: `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'` Sorry to ask obvious questions, it's just these are the things people most often miss.

Comment: The obvious questions **are** most useful. It's my ignorance that makes them *not-so-obvious* to me. So keep shooting, mate. As for your question, the answer is no. I've tried to put that string in the beginning of the *index.js* file but I get an error about unexpected token. Then, I realized that Vue itself works, even though I don't have an import for it neither, so I figured that the router should work too. Where exactly should I place the import of the router? If it's in the *index.js* then I can't get it to work. I've done the webpack compiles but it didn't bring any change...

Comment: Would it be possible to manually link the router somehow? Just for cheating the system for now, I'm thinking.

Comment: I can see you now have an answer your question. I'm glad you're gradually getting everything worked out!

Answer (score 1):

Konrad,
I think you are looking for vue-router.
https://router.vuejs.org/en/

You have your navbar with `<router-link>`s
and then one `<router-view>` which will be replaced with appropriate component configured in `routes`

Your `vapp` is `<router-view>`.

Every view is separate VUE file (component).

It is the best to go with webpack-vue-template to develop more than simple component. If you want to have routing etc, you definitely should use webpack template.
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: I'll definitely check that out. In the current project we're using MaterialCss and VueJs - none of which I have experience with. So I'm trying to be modest not to build something up that's going to bite the next person in the ass. +1