# Unable to create Vue Router instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, .net-core, vue-router

Following [the guide](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) I arrived at the point where I need to create an instance of Vue (which seems to work). However, I also need to provide an instance of Vuew Router into the constructor of Vue, as shown below.

```
const router = new VueRouter({ routes });
const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

Regrettably, it produces the following error. I'm very uncertain on how to deal with it and troubleshooting seems to be rather sparesely documented when [googlearching](https://www.google.se/search?num=50&newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&q=Uncaught+ReferenceError%3A+%22VueRouter%22+is+not+defined&oq=Uncaught+ReferenceError%3A+%22VueRouter%22+is+not+defined&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1.779264.780765.0.781486.5.4.1.0.0.0.277.439.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.3.440.fXq0_dwZzkA).

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: VueRouter is not defined(…)
```

I made sure that I have both packages installed, plus some extras.

```
+-- vue@2.0.8
+-- vue-cli@2.5.1
+-- vue-router@2.0.3
```

I haven't implemented the importing for those two below (not sure where to put in the code, really, and when I tried with my *index.js* it barked not recognizing the token). However, I believe that those are not required because Vue is still recognized and only its router fails to be recognized. If importing would be crutial, I have a feeling that both would fail if omitted.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

The whole thing is extra tricky because there's a decision to run it under Net.Core and not NodeJs, so I might be limited by that. We're won't be using Webpack or Browserify to keep the process running (instead we go the plain *dotnet run*). Not sure if it's relevant info at this stage but I've read that it's supposed to be "*oh, so simple and easy*" but, frankly speaking, it seems to be anything but simple and easy. So I suspect that it's easy if deployed in a certain environment but in my case requiring some hands-on massaging.

What can I look into to investigate the issue further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a basic set up for vue-router, but yes you definitely need to import vue & vue-router to be able to reference them as you are:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use( VueRouter );

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

you'll have to get your import set up functioning for this to work though which I know from another question has been proving tricky.

If you have to move away from imports you can just link to the libaries in your html and omit the 2 import lines at the top, i.e.

```js
Vue.use( VueRouter );

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.3"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: The second example works. The first one produces error in my browser. Is it because of it being embedded?

Comment: yeah I imagine it's the same issue you had earlier - that your set up isn't allowing you to import packages. This is a babel / ES6 compilation issue which you'd have to troubleshoot. Is there not an easy way of breaking out the building of your app from DotNet so you can use webpack or browserify to build it? can you not call commands from `dotnet run`? If you can you could install a vue-cli set up of vue and then call it's `npm run dev` command to build the output.

Comment: This started to be ridiculous - I copied the second sample that you so kindly provided and it **still** didn't work, for duck's sake (typo intended). Then I started poking around and I realized - it's the **order** of execution that screws it up. I put the Vue related JS in my *onload* which but I should execute the Vue related stuff **after** the app div is created. When I moved out to a totally blank file, it worked. This requires a highly contra-intuitive approach. And it should go and quack itself (once again, typo intended), hahaha.

Comment: I'm so close to 10k rep so I don't want to spend any on anything. But I'll ask a buddy to kick in a bounty on this because I feel that you've done an awesome job. And effort should be rewarded!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Have you tried to integerate things like babel and browserify into your project? AFAIK, you should be able to use them to transpile `import` for you, whatever your backend is.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 I've installed Babel but didn't get it to work. Probably due to ignorance. I'm based on .NET.Core under VS Code so I might have missed some of the automagic stuff and simply made a mistake. Is it as simple as googling it or is there a catch to looks out for? I'll do some research myself because I need to understand what's going on but it's nice to know that I'm heading in the right direction and won't get stuck on "oops... IIS won't work with that" etc.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You should be fine as long as your backend server uses http/https ;) Basically, you just set up a frontend dev server which transpiles your frontend src files upon your edit and then reload the browser for you. Our GuyC here have recommended the official [vue-cli](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI) many times. Personally I used [fountain-vue](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-vue/) instead of vue-cli.

Comment: Just one thing to notice: I configured browser-sync's frontend dev server to proxy all backend's apis to solve the CORS issue when the html is from the backend and scripts and styles are from the frontend server.

Comment: I wouldn't say all the frontend toolchain stuff is easy, there are millions of config options to learn and we have to scratch over SO, docs, github issue and all. It's always been a nightmare to me when I tried to learn things like angular and react off work (I mainly use jQuery at work with no frontend automization), but when I finally got a chance to decide everything on the next project, I went on the one-way road with vue and the modern frontend stuff. It took me three or four days to get a nice no-error login page, but well, the time cost was acceptable and I proved it's all possible...

Comment: @PanJunjie fountain-vue looks great, thanks for recommending - I hadn't seen that before but I'll be sure to check it out.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 Sigh... I just realized that Vue [doesn't support template URLs](https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/). So now I have to figure out how to work the darn Webpack. I'm not sure if I'll have Node running on my deployment server, so it all feels a bit shaky and scary. I got the decision to work .NET.Core and Vue and it's going to be **my** problem to make it happen. :)